# What is the difference in between Result Filter and Response Filter in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was going through the MSDN site for Filtering In ASP .NET MVC concept (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) . In the "ASP.NET MVC Filter Types" it has been mentioned that there are 4 filters named :-

1. Authorization filters
2. Action filters
3. Result filters
4. Exception filters

but in the Filter Order section it has been written that

Filters run in the following order:

1. Authorization filters
2. Action filters
3. Response filters
4. Exception filters

So what is this Response Filter ? Are there any difference in between Result Filter and Response filter ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, Result/Response filters are the same thing.

Because Result filters allow you to modify the outgoing HTTP response they're commonly referred to as Response (aka HTTP response) filters.